# Debugger not coming to Button_Click in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.DateTime d1 = default(System.DateTime);
    if (Strings.Len(Strings.Trim(txtName.Text)) == 0)
    {
        msg("Name Must Be Present");
        txtName.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (CatList.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        msg("Select Sex");
        CatList.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (Strings.Len(Strings.Trim(txtMobile.Text)) < 10)
    {
        msg("Invalid Mobile Number");
        txtMobile.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (!Information.IsNumeric(txtMobile.Text))
    {
        msg("Invalid Mobile Number");
        txtMobile.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (Strings.Len(Strings.Trim(txtEmail.Text)) > 0)
    {
        //if (!RegularExpressionValidator1.IsValid)
        //{
        //    msg("Invalid Email ID");
            txtEmail.Focus();
            return;
        //}
    }

    DoctorDTO objDoctor = new DoctorDTO();

    objDoctor.DocName = txtName.Text;
    objDoctor.DocSex = CatList.SelectedItem.Text;
    objDoctor.DocCredential = txtCredential.Text;
    objDoctor.DocAddress = txtAddress.Text;
    objDoctor.DocRTel = txtRtel.Text;
    objDoctor.DocCTel = txtCtel.Text;
    objDoctor.DocMobile = txtMobile.Text;
    objDoctor.DocEmail = txtEmail.Text;
    objDoctor.DocImagePath = Image1.ImageUrl;

    List<DoctorDTO> lstDoctors = objService.GetAllDoctors();

    lstDoctors = new List<DoctorDTO>(
        from l in lstDoctors
        where l.DocProfileID.Equals((Session["userid"].ToString()))
        select l
        );

    if (lstDoctors.Count > 0)
    {
        objService.UpdateAllDoctorDetails(objDoctor); 
    }
    else {
        objService.AddDoctorDetails(objDoctor);
    } 
}
```

In my asp.net page i am fetching certain details in text boxes of the details and i have a button to save the Data
On Button1_Click firstly a java script is called to check whether the data has to be saved or not then only Data will be saved

However the Debugger is not going to Button Click

**Please help someone**

Comment: Have you saved your .aspx Page? I often kick myself for not doing that.

Comment: Can you write the asp code, or where you bind the OnClick event to the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your javascript function return false, Button1_Click will not be fired

Answer (score 3):

In your aspx page you must define the event against the button click.

```
OnClick="Button1_Click"
```

Something like.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Button" OnClientClick="myFunction();" 
            OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Either way should work

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
}
```

Or

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Also watch what magic your javascript is doing